# Setup improvement for planing faces of long boards

Tags: hand-tools, workbench, hand-planing

Apologies in advance for the long intro — I thought it would be relevant to explain the setup I am looking to evolve and why.

I’ve started woodworking with power tools on a balcony, and as such my first bench had to be portable and did not need to be rock solid. I’ve gone with a Bora Centipede (tall version) and have been extremely happy with it for sawing, routing, sanding, assembly, etc.

In the recent months I have been switching to hand tools and non-s4s lumber. I have more space now, but at the outset I was not confident enough in my skills (or in my commitment to hand tools) to build a proper Roubo bench. So I built a Roman bench following Chris Schwarz’s book. I am again extremely happy with it. It works great for planing smaller boards, as well as chiseling, sawing, etc. I still use the Centipede for some tasks (and I still use a track saw for material breakdown).

I have found a gap in this setup with regards to planing. Some tasks are ok:

- On the Roman bench, I can plane the faces of boards up to 60 cm / 24 in long. And I can plane the edges of boards of any length by holding them with a screw clamp.
- On the Centipede braced against a wall, I can traverse a long board.

[image: Roman planing]
[image: Centipede planing]

But neither option is very good for the faces of long boards:

- On the Roman bench, the only alternative is to sit on the board (otherwise it’s too low), but then I can’t plane all of it in one stroke.
- The Centipede is too short.

I appreciate that my setup is highly idiosyncratic. However, since it works for 90% of what I need to do (for now), **I’d like to explore how I might augment it** instead of throwing everything away and starting over with a Roubo- or Nicholson-style bench. I am also hesitant to allocate space permanently to a giant bench (for now).

Some options I’ve considered:

- Get a second Centipede to support longer boards
- Build a Japanese sawhorse (or a couple of them) from 10×10 cm (4×4 in) material
- Build a proper big and heavy bench (would like to avoid, but including for completeness)

Is there something else you would recommend? Am I going against the grain (pun not intended) too much here? :)

Comment: what I am hearing you say is you just need a support for long boards to plane faces.  Why not build a portable/collapsible extension to either of your current benches?

Comment: That makes sense, I guess the two options I listed both match this description. I’d like to avoid reinventing the wheel, so a time-tested design would be my preference (commercial or not). The Japanese sawhorse seems to be one...

Comment: *"but then I can’t plane all of it in one stroke."* I get the reluctance/hesitation in wanting to do this, as it's something I had to tackle myself due to small working surfaces (starting with a mk 4 WorkMate) and then limited space around the 'bench' on top of that, after a move. But it's worth bearing in mind that for a lot of planing — *especially* smoothing if this is an important consideration for you — not being able to take full-length strokes isn't a huge deal. Even where it's highly desirable it's not the end of the world if you can't.

Comment: @Graphus I am primarily focused on flattening; for smoothing I have an escape hatch in the orbital sander (a track saw, a sander and a drill are the only power tools I kept). Besides having to work in sections, I found I had to either plane against the grain or pull the plane at one of the ends. And it seems this way I might not benefit from a longer plane if  I got one… (I am talking about up to 2m boards for tables/credenzas)

Comment: Planes over about a foot long are mostly "jointer planes"  for truing edges for gluing up panels. Smoothing planes, which are a semifinal finishing step for tabletops and such, aren't especially long unless you are comparing them to block planes, shoulder planes, and the like.